# How to customize website for Google first search Result?

Tags: search-engines

I don't know what is terminology used for following examples.

I want to customize my website so when user search it on internet and it will return result look like following example for first search result.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: You build a site with lots of content, Google chooses the subtopics. You have no control over what Google decides to show as those top links.

Comment: This is incorrect. You can demote URLs you do not wish to appear as sitelinks in Google webmaster tools.